# How to use froala events in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, froala

I am using froala in my angular2 project. I have successfully uploaded image but cannot trigger the `image.uploaded` event. In froala document, event is something like this

```
$('.selector').on('froalaEditor.image.uploaded', function (e, editor, response) {
  // Do something here.
});
```

But i am unable to implement this in ts code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more thing which is difficult to find online is how to use methods from froala in angular2.

From [froala documentation](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods), you can see item.action, so you can use it as item.action() in angular2. For example with hiding toolbar.

**TYPESCRIPT**:

```
export class FroalaEditor {
    public editor;
    public model: string = '';
    public options: Object = {
        events: {
            'froalaEditor.initialized': (e, editor) {
                this.editor = editor;
            }
        }
    }

    showToolBar() {
        this.editor.toolbar.show();
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div [froalaEditor]="options" [(froalaModel)]="model"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Events can be registered with options directly as suggested in official documentation.

Ts code

```
 public options: Object = {
      placeholder: "Edit Me",
      events : {
        'froalaEditor.focus' : function(e, editor) {
          console.log(editor.selection.get());
        }
      }
    }
```

template part

```
 <div [froala-editor]="options"></div>
```